# Which sets contain the Harry Potter Phoenix Fawkes mini figure?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

The set 76402 "Dumbledores office" contains an underwhelming baby phoenix "Fawkes" figure which left me wondering if there are more beautiful phoenix minifigures available.

I found 71028-02 Dumbledore with Fawkes.
Is this Fawkes exclusive in 71028 or does it appear in other sets as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [parts list for set 76402](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=76402-1), I believe you're referring to part [41835pb01 "Small Bird with Black Eyes and Bright Light Orange Beak Pattern"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41835pb01):

[image: Bird]

At the time of this writing, that part appears in 24 sets in white, in 18 sets in blue (rather "dark azure"), and in [8 sets in red](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=41835pb01&colorID=5&in=A).

---

The collectible minifig you refer to is set [solhp2-2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=colhp2-2). It contains part [bb1155pb01 "Phoenix with Black Beak and Bright Light Orange Face and Chest Pattern (HP Fawkes)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb1155pb01):

[image: Phoenix]

This [appears in two sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=bb1155pb01&in=S): the aforementioned collectible minifig and set [76394 "Fawkes, Dumbledore’s Phoenix"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76394-1):

[image: phoenix sculpture with mini-phoenix underneath]

Comment: It could be worth mentioning the [older version](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43744pb01) from [4730 Chamber of Secrets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4730-1)